# SQL event logging in ADO.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, logging, ado.net

We want to log sql events and its working but the problem is it always says `sa` as an user. Whereas I would like this to be personalized.

**Is there anyway in ADO.Net where I can pass custom display name so that the logging of sql shows who the user is doing what in my DB?**

I know this question looks quite wierd but this is how my requirement is. Any comments are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't log-in as SA! That's a real big security problem just waiting to happen. Create other SQL users, and use them in your connection string. That will let you control which user is shown on the profile, and also add you quite a bit of security.

Note: You could also log in based on your Windows credentials, which is even safer in some production environments, but you might not want to worry about it right now.

Comment: My Question is even if I change the user still SQL will log event for that user. Please note we are using one DB user for all our application user. Is there any way where we could pass custom display name to sql for event logging only.